# Does the perimeter of a semicircle include the diameter?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

Is the perimeter of a semicircle $(\pi)(\text{radius})$   or  $(\pi)(\text{radius})+\text{diameter}$?

Comment: The second, of course

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: yes. it is $\pi r + d$ where $r$ is the radius and $d$ is the diameter because you add half of the perimeter of the circle to the diameter

Comment: but in many websites it says its just   pi x R

Comment: @TomMathew: You'll find in mathematics that terminology can vary from author to author. (We can't even agree on whether the [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) include zero!) Context is key. If someone shows a semicircular *region* and asks its perimeter, then the diameter would certainly need to be included. On the other hand, if someone is discussing circular *arcs*, then it may be not-entirely-unreasonable to use "perimeter" to describe their lengths as a friendlier alternative to the stuffy-sounding "arc length".

Comment: To quote Lewis Carroll's [Humpty Dumpty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty): *"When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."*

Comment: @Blue : Thanks Sir, That's the most perfect answer I've received ...I asked this doubt in many other websites but none of them could give me a satisfying answer.

Comment: @TomMathew: Good to know. :) I'll transfer the comments to a proper answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Transferring from a comment.)

You'll find in mathematics that terminology can vary from author to author. (We can't even agree on whether the [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) include zero!)

Context is key. If someone shows a semicircular *region* and asks its perimeter, then the diameter would certainly need to be included. On the other hand, if someone is discussing a semicircular *arc*, then it may be *not-entirely-unreasonable* to use "perimeter" to identify its length, perhaps as a friendlier alternative to the stuffy-sounding "arc length".

To quote Lewis Carroll's [Humpty Dumpty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty):

> When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the [semi-circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicircle) is one dimensional locus of points that forms half of a circle.  It consists of diameter & half the circumference of a circle.

[image]

Hence the perimeter of a semi-circle is $$\frac{2\pi R}{2}+2R=\color{blue}{\pi R+2R}$$